# How to connect Yield farm frontend to Matic/Polygon

Tags: pancakeswap, frontend, polygon

The idea I am following is to create yield farm like https://polyvertex.finance/.
Backend with contracts is clear to some extent thanks to tutorials. Problems come with frontend for which I barely can find a clue.

All started with forking https://github.com/goosedefi/goose-frontend-farms as it is a popular one to fork, though I tried to deploy it even without any changes and I ran into bugs one after one. After dozens of tries, I decided it will be better to take this https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend as an original (at least, it deploys, even though without my changes yet). I get an understanding how to connect the contracts. The main issue is the following:

These two projects are based on binance. My goal is however Matic/Polygon. How to correctly delete the connection to binance and establish the new one to Matic? I am almost sure there is a starting point, one file that establishes the connections, and other ones are linked then to it. But I am clueless what this first step should be.

I guess, without proper guidance on first steps I will likely start somewhere from the middle or the end, losing the crucial points out of sight.

By the way, there are Matic farms frontend repositories like https://github.com/8ballfinance/farming-ui though their static folder is incomprehensible.

Any help, hint, guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: The pancake-frontend uses `Web3ReactProvider` in the Providers.tsx, it is package that allows connecting a frontend with a wallet. I suggest to start looking for their uses and change accordingly.

Comment: I'm working on the same issue. Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix, the RPC urls are defined in the .env.production file you can change them there to Matic or the testnet.